# Issue with Texture Mapping on Models without UVs

Tags: texture-mapping

We are in the process of porting a program, originally developed in Unreal Engine for displaying 3D models, to ThreeJs. However, we have encountered a specific issue. In Unreal Engine, we could apply materials like wood or tile to models without UV attributes, and the textures displayed correctly. In ThreeJs, however, it appears that texture mapping requires the model vertices to have UV coordinates. Could anyone advise on how to achieve a similar functionality in ThreeJs as in Unreal Engine?